# How to set input[type="text"] width and height so it corresponds to standard width and height of block elements?

Tags: html, css, input, size

For some reason, if I set width and height to text input element it gets a bigger size from all other block elements with the same width and height

What would be a formula for width and height values for the input element so it has the exact same size as a div with the width = x and height = y?

see an example here: https://codepen.io/alanklm/pen/MWpRgEe

html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="a">
<button>a</button>
<div>a</div>
```

css:

```
*
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
  
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

input
{
    background-color: coral;
}

button
{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

div
{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

p.s. I tried to put input into div, and size div instead, while giving input container 100% width and 100% height - it leads to the exact same result, input goes over the div's borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of default `padding: 1px 2px` on text inputs. Just set `padding: 0px`

```css
*
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    
    padding: 0px;
  
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

input
{
    background-color: coral;
}

button
{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

div
{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="a">
<button>a</button>
<div>a</div>
```

Comment: oh, I feel stupid xD how could I miss checking the padding. This is the perfect solution. Thank you!

Comment: Probably even better solution to give input "box-sizing: border-box;", then you can have both padding, and a propper size.